# WD19TB Dock mirrors 2 external displays instead of extending

Tags: drivers, dell, 19.10, xps, dock

I'm running Ubuntu 19.10 on a Dell XPS 13 7390 2-in-1. I'm using the WD19TB dock to connect 2 external displays. Everything works except for the fact that my OS only detects 1 external display and mirrors the output to both external displays. I've updated the dock and laptop firmware the latest versions. I suspected a newer kernel might solve the issue but booting a 5.4 kernel didn't change anything.

Both displays are detected on Windows. Any ideas how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Someone on the dell forums found a solution. Using the right side thunderbolt port fixes the issue.

https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/WD19TB-Dock-mirrors-2-external-displays-instead-of-extending-on/td-p/7441015